# Check URL in Object, and return nearest sibling

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-context

I have an API that is going to be spitting out a few dozen objects, each one containing a `promo_url` and a `promo_number`, in order to do dynamic number swapping on my Gatsby site. Like so:

```
 [{
    "promo_url": "/promo1",
    "promo_number": "665-894-3142"
  },
  {
    "promo_url": "/promo2",
    "promo_number": "493-441-7386"
  },
  {
    "promo_url": "/promo3",
    "promo_number": "549-823-5785"
  },
  {
    "promo_url": "/promo4",
    "promo_number": "553-747-1261"
  },
  {
    "promo_url": "/promo5",
    "promo_number": "253-741-2776"
  }]
```

Essentially, what I need to do is find and set the user's `referral` URL, check through the data, find the URL that matches it, and then pass the related phone number to my components through a context, however I have no idea how to check the objects, find the matching URL, and then pass the related phone number. Does anyone have any ideas on how/where I should begin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a reduce function here to return the promo number. [The reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is great at taking data and simplifying it down. Here I am just iterating through it similar to a filter but what is cool with reduce is you can see defaults for the return and I find it more readable sometimes.

```
const apiResults = [
  {
   "promo_url": "/promo1",
    "promo_number": "665-894-3142"
  },
  {
    "promo_url": "/promo2",
    "promo_number": "493-441-7386"
  },
  {
    "promo_url": "/promo3",
    "promo_number": "549-823-5785"
  },
  {
    "promo_url": "/promo4",
    "promo_number": "553-747-1261"
  },
  {
    "promo_url": "/promo5",
    "promo_number": "253-741-2776"
  }
]
const referralUrl = "/promo5"

const promoNumber = apiResults.reduce((promoNumber, result) => {
  const IS_USER_PROMO = referralUrl === results.promo_url
  if(IS_USER_PROMO) {
    return result.promo_number
  }
  return promoNumber
}, "")
```